# Simplest way to draw a grid with MonoTouch

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, grid

I want to draw a grid like this:
[image]

I want the ability to style the color of each rectangle individual. I also want to be able to set a specific rectangle to be transparent.

What is the simplest way to draw a grid like this in MonoTouch / C#?

Answer (score 1):

The code presents the drawing of the grid on the panel but you could use anything as your canvas control. Check the following code:

```
        int numHorisontal = 20;
        int numVertical;
        int squareDim = 10;
        int xOffset = 30;
        int yOffset = 30;
        void panel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= numVertical; i++)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(xOffset, yOffset + i * squareDim), new Point(xOffset + 20 * squareDim, yOffset + i * squareDim));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < numHorisontal; i++)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(xOffset + i * squareDim, yOffset), new Point(xOffset + i * squareDim, yOffset + 20 * squareDim));
            }
        }
```

`numHorisontal` is the number of horisontal squares in the grid and `numVertical` is the vertical number of squares. The `squareDim` is the size of the one square side. If you want to set the color of the square on the indexes i and j than you could use the following method. If you want to set some squares transparent, than the canvas should be also transparent (set the background color of the canvas to transparent).

```
private void SetColor(int i, int j, Color color, Graphics g)
{
    g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(color), new Rectangle(i * squareDim, j + squareDim, squareDim, squareDim));
}
```

**Note** that this is the code as if you want to draw using C# in WinForms and you could use the similar code like this in any other technology.